# Char library which can scale the x axis correctly

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I am looking for a chart library in JavaScript.

It have to support Lines (I suppose all charting libraries do that).
I have to support zooming, due to high amount of data.

The problem I have found while using other libraries is scaling the x axis.

I get data by strings:

```
y=[43,56,34,63....]
x=[24/04/12 22:47,...]
```

But the number of lines and the interval is specified by the user. Meaning that I can have 50 data or 500 data. The problem comes when I input these dates and times. I cant find a library that will look into the length of the string and then just show maybe 4-5 of them when zoomed out, and show more detailed when zoomed in.

Money is not a problem, but it need to have a trial version.

Edit: I have tried libraries which allow me to set a start date, and then the interval by the points. But my intervals are not constant, so that cant be used either.

Answer (score 0):

Try amCharts. This library supports dates as series. Your job will be to convert your date string into JavaScript Date  Object, it's quite a simple task. Here is an example of a chart with date-based data:
http://amcharts.com/javascript/line-chart-with-date-based-data/

Another one with date/time based data:
http://amcharts.com/javascript/area-chart-with-time-based-data/

You can download and try this library.